# How to make Ubuntu detect my system jack as speakers so I can have 5.1 sound?

Tags: 12.04, sound, acer

I have an Acer 5738G with Ubuntu 12.04, I modified the configurations to have 5.1 sound. It works, but my problem is that only my laptop speakers are detected as speakers in sound settings, when I plug in my system audio jack, Ubuntu detects headphones and ones that only have 2.0 sound.

So how can I make Ubuntu detect my system jack as speakers?

Answer (score 1):

for 5.1 you must have hdmi or 3 color jacks . 5.1 cant work with only 1 jack . if you have hdmi you can use it hdmi-supported sound sytem or you can a translater hdmi to your cable

Answer (score 0):

In what shape or form did you modify your speakers? Did you internally upgrade your motherboard or did you add speakers around on the side of your laptop?